# How to put a contorl in the AssetLibrary thumbnail view?

Tags: 2010, xslt

I have an asset library in which I want to put a check box to give user the select all functionality on Asset Library thumbnail view. As a SharePoint beginner I don't know from where to start? I searched over internet and found that I whould edit AssetPicker.xsl. But don't know what should I do?

[image: Sample image for required output]

Please provide steps or any reference link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with a bit of jQuery.

```
jQuery('#pickerimages').before('<div><input type="checkbox" id="cbx-selectall" />select all</div>');
jQuery('#cbx-selectall').click(function(){      
    jQuery('#pickerimages input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', jQuery(this).attr('checked') == 'checked');
});
```

Be careful to use the full jQuery function name and not the $ shorthand, because from what I can see, the Thumbnails.aspx page makes use of a $ function which is not jQuery.

If you need guidance on how to include/use jQuery in a SharePoint page, [see this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544538/JQuery-with-SharePoint-2010)